# Get (join) list where linked to optional List via Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, virtual

I created my database via EF, and now (using LINQ) I want to return a list (called posts) where it is linked to its optional list (called flags)

In the example below, you can see I give table Post a virtual List of flags (which means optional right?)

MODEL :

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dateapproved { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Flag> Flags { get; set; }
}

public class Flag
{
    public int FlagID { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
}
```

EF :

```
public class sampleProject : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Flag> Flags { get; set; }
}
```

How would I get a list of Posts where there is a link to flags, and Dateapproved is not null?

Ofcourse this won't work, because the declaration is expecting a Post, and is getting a list of flags instead :

```
List<Post> postlist = context.Flags.Where(x => x.Post.DateApproved != null).ToList();
```

I know of the "Include" function, but not sure it will work here

What is the best practice here?
Should I split it somehow into more steps?

Comment: Virtual doesn't really mean optional. It being null (or allowing a zero length list of Lfags) is a good enough way to define "optional". Virtual is to do with inheritance and is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: For the actual question I would have thought `List<Post> postlist = context.Where(x => x.DateApproved != null).ToList();` would get a list of all the posts where DateApproved is not null and Post should have its Flags if they are set...

Comment: Also your Flag class seems odd. It has a separate `PostID` and `Post` object on it. If you have Post is PostID not irrelevant? And does a Flag really need to know what post it is on? Is it not enough that the Post knows what flags it has?

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes I think you are correct the Post object on Flag is not needed, I only that in later because I was getting desperate. I will quickly test everyone's answers and Edit the question to fix that. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Just a note on your second comment, I only want the posts returned which are linked to a flag, your answer will only return even if there are no flags linked

Comment: Ah, misunderstood but testCoder's answer has the modification I'd have made in it already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I get a list of Posts where there is a link to flags, and
>   Dateapproved is not null?

Try this:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Include("Flags").Where(x => x.Flags.Any() && x.Dateapproved != null).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks very much testCoder, the Any() method works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  var result = from p in Posts
               join f in Flags on p.PostId equals f.PostId
               where f.Post.DateApproved != null
               select p;
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, I'm sure think this will work as well, but PostID is already linked via models, so it feels like an extra step linking it again. But thanks for taking the time looking at my question